# Javascript pull data from string?

Tags: javascript, parsing

I have a long URL that contains some data that I need to pull. I am able to get the end of the URL by doing this:

```
var data = window.location.hash;
```

When I do `alert(data);` I receive a long string like this:

```
#access_token=0u2389ruq892hqjru3h289r3u892ru3892r32235423&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600
```

*note in the example the access token is not valid, just random numbers I input for example purpose*

Now that I have that long string stored in a variable, how can I parse out just the access token value, so everything in between the first '=' and '&. So this is what I need out of the string:

```
0u2389ruq892hqjru3h289r3u892ru3892r32235423
```

I was reading up on php explode, and others java script specific stuff like strip but couldn't get them to function as needed. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/F75ev/1/)</kbd> (look in your debug console)

You will want to split the string by the token `'&'` first to get your key/value pairs:

```
var kvpairs = document.location.hash.substring(1).split('&');
```

Then, you will want to split each kvpair into a key and a value:

```
for (var i = 0; i < kvpairs.length; i++) {
    var kvpair = kvpairs[i].split('=');

    var k = kvpair[0];
    var v = kvpair[1];

    if (k != 'access_token')
        continue;

    console.log(v); //Here's your access token.
}
```

---

Here is a version wrapped into a function that you can use easily:

```
function getParam(hash, key) {
    var kvpairs = hash.substring(1).split('&');

    for (var i = 0; i < kvpairs.length; i++) {
        var kvpair = kvpairs[i].split('=');

        var k = kvpair[0];
        var v = kvpair[1];

        if (k != key)
            continue;

        return v;
    }    

    return null;
}
```

Usage:

```
getParam(document.location.hash, 'access_token');
```

Comment: You could make this into a function that accepts the key to make it more reusable.

Comment: @TheSharpieOne True, but I bet there are other SO answers that already do that!

Comment: True, he clearly didn't even try to look for the answer before posting the question.

Comment: hmm...Actually I have been trying to resolve this issue for the past two days. Worked with a few people off of SO to try and resolve it, but to no avail. So I came back for more help. Your comments don't add to anything on this thread so why waste time typing it?

Answer (score 3):

```
data.split("&")[0].split("=")[1]
```

Comment: If he can guarantee that it will always be the first k/v pair, then this would be the shortest example.

Comment: yeah - he said that in his question so I was just going by that.

Comment: I don't see where he says that.

Comment: he says: "everything in between the first '=' and '&'"

Comment: He does, but he's pointing at the example string. He never makes a guarantee that it will always be in that position, though it is likely it will be. **An even faster example would use substring, since the token is a fixed length string, if it were guaranteed to always be at the front position.**

Comment: eh, I guess he can comment on what his criteria are, if he needs anything more.

Answer (score 2):

```
var str = "#access_token=0u2389ruq892hqjru3h289r3u892ru3892r32235423&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600";

var requiredValue = str.split('&')[0].split('=')[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd use regex in case value=key pair changes position

```
var data = "#token_type=Bearer&access_token=0u2389ruq892hqjru3h289r3u892ru3892r32235423&expires_in=3600";
RegExp("access_token=([A-Za-z0-9]*)&").exec(data)[1];
```

output

```
"0u2389ruq892hqjru3h289r3u892ru3892r32235423"
```

Comment: This is probably the best quick and dirty way of getting it.

Comment: drat you beat me to it - here's my version, maybe you can figure out why it doesn't work: data.replace(/#[^&]*&\([^#]*\).*/g,"worked");

Comment: Hey @baordog , your regex matches whole string, this part `#[^&]*&` matches first key-value pair with surrounding symbols and next part `([^#]*)` matches everything else. If you tried to match everything EXCEPT the needed value and replace it with nothing I don't think that regex is the way to do it, it isn't designed for inverse searches.

Comment: Good catch, I was way off base on that one.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like I'm a bit late on this. Here's my attempt at a version that parses URL parameters into a map and gets any param by name.

```
var str = "#access_token=0u2389ruq892hqjru3h289r3u892ru3892r32235423&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600";

function urlToMap(url){
    var startIndex = Math.max(url.lastIndexOf("#"), url.lastIndexOf("?"));
    url = url.substr(startIndex+1);
    var result = {};
    url.split("&").forEach(function(pair){
        var x = pair.split("=");
        result[x[0]]=x[1];
    });
    return result;
}

function getParam(url, name){
    return urlToMap(url)[name];
}

console.log(getParam(str, "access_token"));
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer to your question directly (what's between this and that), you would need to use indexOf and substring functions.

Here's a little piece of code for you.

```
    function whatsBetween (_strToSearch, _leftText, _rightText) {
        var leftPos = _strToSearch.indexOf(_leftText) + _leftText.length;
        var rightPos = _strToSearch.indexOf(_rightText, leftPos);
        if (leftPos >= 0 && leftPos < rightPos)
            return _strToSearch.substring(leftPos, rightPos);
        return "";
    }
```

Usage:

```
alert(whatsBetween, data,"=","#");
```

That said, I'd rather go with a function like crush's...

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var data = window.location.hash;
var d1 = Array();
d1 = data.split("&")
var myFilteredData = Array();
for( var i=0;i<d1.length;i++ )
{
 var d2 = d1[i].split("=");
 myFilteredData.push(d2[1]); //Taking String after '='
}
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: How would you know which index of the filtered data is the data for the parameter you want? A map could be more suitable here.

Comment: Of course. If you want some specific you can put an if(d2[0]==myspecificString){ myfilterData[myspecificString] = d2[1]; }